# upload multiPartFormData to Laravel server using Alamofire 4, swift 3

Tags: swift, laravel, alamofire, laravel-5.3

I am trying to upload multiple images to my live Laravel 5.3 web-app that I am using as a backend for iOS. On the website I can upload images etc no problem and with a native PHP script I can upload images to a folder on the website, but I am having trouble using Swift 3, Alamofire 4 and backend Laravel 5.x

When the ios user hits upload, they navigate to a route on my backend that should move the file (image) from the request to the servers folder, create a filename etc, and then create the row in the database.

I can get a status code of 200 for hitting the route, but I can't seem to

A. debug the request through laravels response error messages which I can usually see in other Alamofire.request .get and .post methods 
B. move the image to the server
or C. create a row in the db

Can someone give me some advice please? I am a self taught programmer

```
PHP:
// the $request holds the payload
public function store(Request $request) {

   return $request;

   // also tried 
   // $file = $request->file('file');
   // $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   // $user = Auth::user();
   // $file->move('uploads' . $user->id . '/photos', $filename;
   // $user->create(['filename' => $filename .... etc]);
   // $user->save();
   // return redirect()->back();
```

Swift 3, Alamofire 4:
    @IBAction func upload(_ sender: Any) {

```
    let URL = try! URLRequest(url: "https://mywebsite.com/store", method: .post)
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(self.imageData!, withName: "store", fileName: "test.png", mimeType: "image/png")
        }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: {
            encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseData { response in
                    debugPrint("SUCCESS RESPONSE: \(response)")
                    debugPrint(response.debugDescription)
                    print(response)
                    print(response.data)
                    print(response.result)
                    print(response.request)
                    print(response.description)
                    print(response.debugDescription)
                    print(response.metrics)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                // hide progressbas here
                print("ERROR RESPONSE: \(encodingError)")
            }
        })

When I get a 200 html response, There is normally a Laravel web page that gets included here allowing room for debugging with the API I am trying to consume. But it is cut short and I don't know why 

eg 
(Response) <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x60800003d3e0> { URL: websitegoeshere } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Sun, 08 Jan 2017 21:10:21 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.11.5";
    "Set-Cookie" = "XSRF-
   .... rest of Laravel web-page for debugging usually goes here .
   .... and yes it is enabled
```

Comment: Do you have any csrf protection? Can you even retrieve a basic page? Is it an nginx server? Have you tried using https? If your not using https make sure the URL is whitelisted in your app

Comment: Yes. Yes elsewhere but not here. Yes it is. I am using https and i can login/signup/get/post elsewhere, its just the image upload I am having trouble with.

Comment: You said you're using csrf protection - it could be that preventing your app hitting your web service as it doesnt have the token to send

Comment: Trying again now with dropzone js inside form div that has csrf_token() .. current error = _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, NSErrorPeerAddressKey

Comment: randomly try commenting out the `\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,` line in the `app/Http/Kernal.php` and see what happens

Comment: I have these api routes temporarily excluded from csrf protection in development